# GDB Remote Debugging - Cannot instantiate printer for default visualizer

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, gdb, remote-debugging

Setting up remote gdb debugging in eclipse . The debugger will step through the code just fine but, all of the variables show the following error:

> 1) Failed to execute MI command:
>   -var-create - var_Name Error message from debugger back end: Cannot instantiate printer for default visualizer

**Basically, values don't show up for the variables.**
Is there a setting for the .gdbinit file to fix this, or some other setting in eclipse?

- The remote device uses NFS to mount the localhost /path/to/app
- compiler: gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf
- localhost: running linux mint 19.2 and using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb
- remote: gdbserver :port /path/to/app

  ```
  user@localhost:/ gdb --version
  GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Eclipse Main window: Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Debug -> GDB : Under Pretty Printing region, Deselect "Enable pretty printers in variable/expression tree"

Then click "Apply" and "Apply and Close" viola the variables now print out during remote debug sessions. No change to my .gdbinit file was needed.

Perhaps I am not using python-enabled GDB... I am not sure.