# Loading NLohmann JSON's Pretty Printer Makes Other Data Type Unreadable When Debugging in Eclipse-CDT

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, pretty-print, nlohmann-json

I've recently added the pretty printer for *JSON for Modern C++* (A.K.A. *nlohmann JSON*) to my *Eclipse* project.  The problem is now whenever I try to view other data types in *Eclipse*, such as `int` or `bool` variables, it displays the following error message:

> Failed to execute MI command:
> -var-create - * **[variable name]**
> Error message from debugger back end:
> Cannot instantiate printer for default visualizer

Everything goes back to normal if I remove the JSON pretty printer from my .gdbinit file.  I also attempted to turn off the option "enable pretty printers in the variable/expression tree", as was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886832/gdb-remote-debugging-cannot-instantiate-printer-for-default-visualizer).  While the variables do display properly once that option is disabled, it also disables the pretty printers for both the STL and *JSON for Modern C++*.

So, how do I get *Eclipse* to both use the pretty printer for JSON objects and display the values of all of the other data types when debugging?

#### Additional Information

- Compiler: MinGW-W64 10.0.0
- Debugger: GDB 13.1 (MinGW-W64)
- *JSON for Modern C++* version: 3.11.2